# Variable does not remain after calling 2nd script and ending loop (Python)

Tags: python, loops

I am running script 2 from script 1 but the output of script 2 is not stored as a variable in script 1.

script1

```
def main():
    selection = int(raw_input("Enter Selection: "))
    if selection == 1:
        a = 1
        import script2
        result = script2.doit(a)
        print result
        return True

    elif selection == 0:
        return False

while main():
    pass

print result
```

script 2

```
def doit(a):
    return a+2
```

Although result gets printed after an iteration, it is not stored as "result" after I end the loop. print result outside the loop gives the error "NameError: name 'result' is not defined".

Comment: What you need to archive here ?

Comment: Can you please describe your problem a little bit more? What is your expectation? Where should result be stored?

Comment: result is a local var of function main(). If you want to use result outside of main() type 'global result' (without qoutes) in the body of main()

Comment: What do you mean "stored" ? "stored" where ?

Comment: in python3 it works tho.

Comment: Thanks A False Name. Making the variable global in the main body of the function solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding global result to the main body of main() does the job. Credits to A False Name for the answer. Thanks!

```
def main():
    global result
    ......
```

Comment: Using `global` does work. But it's highly discouraged to use `global`, because it will make your code very very confusing and hard to debug. Instead, use `return` to pass back any result you want to use in the calling scope. Also, it's best to keep all imports at the top of the file, and not nested inside functions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Answer (score 1):

It's because a is a local variable. When your main function returns a value, local variables are cleared. You should either pass it as reference or return the value and re-assign to a global variable.